# How to update multi select dynamically using jQuery POST JSP and servlets

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, select

I'm using a Java Servlet and a JSP file that contains subjects and categories.
When I access the JSP page using my browser, the doGET method is used, in which I declare all the lists of subjects and categories I need to fill in the multi select forms.

What I want to do is, using jQuery, each time my user changes the selected categories in the appropriate multi select form, the content of the subjects' multi select changes automatically **and without refreshing the web page**.

The relation between categories and subjects is sent to the JSP file in a HashMap (category -> subjects), but I didn't figure out how I could use it.

A friend told me that in order to update dynamically the subjects in the multi select, I must use the doPost method with jQuery and send the updated list back to the JSP page (see my doPOST method below, in which for the moment, I'm trying to display the list of selected categories dynamically.

But this code doesn't work: my POST is sent according to FireBug, but the multi select does not update. Have I forgotten something?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    SubjectDAO subjectDao;
    RelationDAO relationDao;
    TripletDAO tripletDao;
    CollectionDAO collectionDao;

    try
    {
        //Récupération de la session courante
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        int idCollection = 1; //Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("idCollection"));
        //TODO: Remplacer le 1 par le commentaire quand les collections marcheront bien

        //Initialisation des DAO nécessaires
        tripletDao = daoFactory.getTripletDAO();
        collectionDao = daoFactory.getCollectionDAO(); //DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(DAOFactory.MYSQL).getCollectionDAO();
        subjectDao = daoFactory.getSubjectDAO();
        relationDao = daoFactory.getRelationDAO();

        //Formation des listes nécessaires
        List<Subject> listSubject = subjectDao.selectAll(false, collectionDao.selectId(idCollection)); //Tous les sujets de la collec' courante
        List<Relation> listRelation = relationDao.selectAll(false, collectionDao.selectId(idCollection)); //Toutes les relations de la collec' courante
        List<Triplet> listTriplet = tripletDao.selectAll(false, collectionDao.selectId(idCollection)); //Tous les triplets de la collec' courante

        //TODO: Voir ce qu'on peut faire pour éviter l'utilisation des listes ci-dessous!
        ArrayList<String> entitledOfSubjects = new ArrayList<String>(listOfSubjectsEntitled(session, listSubject));
        ArrayList<String> entitledOfRelations = new ArrayList<String>(listOfRelationsEntitled(session, listRelation));

        //Récupération de la liste des catégories (de la collection courante)
        Subject sCategory = subjectDao.selectSystem("CATEGORY");
        Relation rIs = relationDao.selectSystem("ISA");
        Relation rIn = relationDao.selectSystem("IN CATEGORY");

        //La liste listCategory2 contient tous les triplets qui contiennent "ISA CATEGORY". Elle s'appelle listCategory2 parce que listCategory c'est celle de la sidebar!
        List<Triplet> listCategory2 = tripletDao.selectAll(-1, rIs.getId(), sCategory.getId(), TripletType.SUBJET, TripletType.SUBJET, false, true, collectionDao.selectId(idCollection));

        //Liste des différents compléments des triplets de la collec' courante
        ArrayList<Subject> listComplement = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        for (int i=0; i<listTriplet.size(); i++)
        {
            Subject s = listTriplet.get(i).getSComplement();
            if (!subjectIsInList(session, s, listComplement) && s!=null && subjectIsInList(session, listTriplet.get(i).getSSubject(), listSubject) 
                    && relationIsInList(session, listTriplet.get(i).getRelation(), listRelation))
            {
                listComplement.add(s);
            }
        }

        //Liste des triplets de la collection courante qui ont pour relation "IN CATEGORY"
        List<Triplet> listTripletSysteme = tripletDao.selectAllByRelation(rIn.getId(), collectionDao.selectId(idCollection)); //(true, collectionDao.selectId(idCollection)); 

        //Liste des différentes catégories des compléments relevés précédemment
        ArrayList<Subject> listComplementCategory = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        for (int i=0; i<listTripletSysteme.size(); i++)
        {
            Subject s = listTripletSysteme.get(i).getSComplement();
            if (!subjectIsInList(session, s, listComplementCategory) && s!=null && subjectIsInList(session, listTripletSysteme.get(i).getSSubject(), listComplement))
            {
                listComplementCategory.add(s);
            }
        }

        //Variables à envoyer à la page JSP
        request.setAttribute("listSubject", listSubject);
        request.setAttribute("listRelation", listRelation);
        request.setAttribute("listCategory2", listCategory2); //session au lieu de request pour la sidebar
        request.setAttribute("listComplementCategory", listComplementCategory);
        request.setAttribute("listComplement", listComplement);

        //TODO: Use of these deprecated by Joe
        request.setAttribute("entitledOfSubjects", entitledOfSubjects);
        request.setAttribute("entitledOfRelations", entitledOfRelations);

        //HashMap (Titre de Catégorie -> liste de titres de sujets lui appartenant)
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> categorySubjectsHashMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        for (int i=0; i<listCategory2.size(); i++)
        {
            Subject categorie = listCategory2.get(i).getSSubject();
            String entitled = categorie.getEntitled((String) session.getAttribute("lang"));
            ArrayList<String> listeSujetsCategorie = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int j=0; j<listTripletSysteme.size(); j++)
            {
                Triplet tripletSysteme = listTripletSysteme.get(j);
                if (tripletSysteme.getSComplement().getEntitled((String) session.getAttribute("lang")).equals(entitled) && 
                        !listeSujetsCategorie.contains(tripletSysteme.getSSubject().getEntitled((String) session.getAttribute("lang"))))
                {
                    listeSujetsCategorie.add(tripletSysteme.getSSubject().getEntitled((String) session.getAttribute("lang")));
                }
            }

            categorySubjectsHashMap.put(entitled, listeSujetsCategorie);
        }

        request.setAttribute("categorySubjectsHashMap", categorySubjectsHashMap);

        //request.setAttribute("listTriplet", listTriplet);

        //Subject sCategory = subjectDao.selectSystem("CATEGORY");
        //Relation rIs = relationDao.selectSystem("ISA");

        /*CollectionDAO collectionDao = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(DAOFactory.MYSQL).getCollectionDAO();
        //int idCollection = Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("idCollection"));
        //List<Triplet> listCategory = tripletDao.selectAll(-1, rIs.getId(), sCategory.getId(), TripletType.SUBJET, TripletType.SUBJET, false, true, collectionDao.selectId(idCollection));
        //request.setAttribute("listCategory", listCategory);
        //Sert à "overrider" idCollection*/

        //int id = add(request);
    } 
    catch (DAOException e) 
    {
        log.error("An error occured", e);

        request.setAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-PAGES/Other/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
    // Set page title
    request.setAttribute("title", "Creation");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-PAGES/Creation/creation.jsp").forward(request, response);

    //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    //String root = (String) session.getAttribute("root");
    //response.sendRedirect(root + "creation");
    //TODO: fix root = null
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
    //ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] selectedSubjectCategories = request.getParameter("selectedSubjectCategories").split(",");

    ArrayList<String> entitledOfSubjects = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<selectedSubjectCategories.length; i++)
    {
        entitledOfSubjects.add(selectedSubjectCategories[i]);
    }

    request.setAttribute("entitledOfSubjects", entitledOfSubjects);
    }
```

Also, here is the snippets of the JSP file that contain the two multi selects, the first one being the one in which I select my categories and the second one in which I want to display dynamically the subjects that belong to the selected categories:

```
    <div id="subjectCategoriesDiv">
      <select name="subjectCategories" multiple="multiple" id="subjectCategories">
      <option value="None">-- NONE --</option>
        <c:forEach items="${listCategory2}" var="triplet">
                <option value="<c:out value="${triplet.SSubject.getEntitled(lang)}" />"><c:out value="${triplet.SSubject.getEntitled(lang)}" /></option>
            </c:forEach>
      </select>
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()  
                {
                    $('#subjectCategories').change(function()
                        {
                            var selectedOptions = $('#subjectCategories option:selected');
                            var selectedValues = $.map(selectedOptions ,function(option) 
                            {
                                return option.value;
                            }).join(',');

                            $.ajax({
                                   type: "POST",
                                   url: "creation",
                                   data: 'selectedSubjectCategories='+selectedValues
                                 });
                        }
                    );
                }).change();
      </script>
    </div>

    <div class="subjectsListDiv">
      <select name="subjectslist" multiple="multiple" id="subjectslist">
        <c:forEach items="${entitledOfSubjects}" var="subject">
                <option value="<c:out value="${subject}" />"><c:out value="${subject}" /></option>      
            </c:forEach>
      </select>
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()  
            {

            });
      </script>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.